# A second order differential equation variation on a wave equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I derived a field equation which is a variation on a wave equation: $\rho = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t \partial x} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t \partial y} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t \partial z}$.
Has this simple expression been studied and have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

No. I do not expect this to have been well studied, nor given a special name in the literature, as this equation does not appear to make sense for describing a physical system.

---

Long answer:

From a physics perspective, this looks strange geometrically. It looks like you are mixing up scalars and vectors. So this makes it unlikely to be useful for describing a physical system, and thus not studied enough to have a well known name in the literature.

Assuming $u$ is a scalar field, after slight rearranging we have this:
$$\rho = (\partial_t)(\partial_t - \partial_x - \partial_y - \partial_z)u$$
and since partial derivatives commute
$$\rho = (\partial_t - \partial_x - \partial_y - \partial_z)(\partial_t)u$$

So we might as well define a new scalar field $s=\partial_t u$. Given $s$ we can solve for $u$, so then we just need to solve for the scalar field $s$.

$$\rho = (\partial_t - \partial_x - \partial_y - \partial_z)s$$

For $\rho = 0$, for any differentiable function of one variable $F$, a possible solution is
$$ s(t,x,y,z) = F(t - x - y - z) $$

Note that even this "wave equation" is strange, in that it has picked out a special direction any wave must propagate. This convinces me your differential equation is unlikely to naturally show up in a physical system, and thus is unlikely to have been well studied enough to give it a recognizable special name.

Comment: Pertinent and appropriate comments @Qvinton.

Comment: Is it possible to view this equation as a generalization of a wave equation? In a standard wave equation, there is the same second time derivative of u. If and only if the derivative with respect to time is exactly equal to each of the three spatial derivatives for the function u, the result is a wave equation.